# How to take input in java where array length is not defined?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

My input is in this format:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Alice
```

The array length is not known.
I coded it this way:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            arr.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        String player = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: have you debugged through the code? How far does it get? When do you expect `hasNextLine()` to return false?

Comment: It's an infinte loop even after reading 6. How to come out of the `while` loop?

Comment: I would suggest just reading the first line as a whole, then splitting it on spaces and parsing each part separately. `Scanner` is remarkably hard to use "properly".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon Skeet. What's the most efficient way to take such kind of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `hasNextInt` to check for integer input. Once no more integers, then just use `next()` to read the player.

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    arr.add(sc.nextInt());
}
String player = sc.next();

arr.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println(player);
```

Example input's supported

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70
Alice

10 20 30 40
50 60 70 Alice

10 20 30
40
50
60 70 Alice

10 20 30
40 50
60 70
Alice
```

output

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
Alice
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing `java.util.InputMismatchException` is because you provided input "Alice" to the statement `sc.nextInt()`, and the scanner is telling you that it doesn't know how to convert a `java.lang.String` input to an int (which is the return type of [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())).

Here's a very simple example that reproduces the same behavior:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();
```

If you run those two lines and enter a non-integer, like "d", it will throw an exception:

```
d
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at a91.main(a91.java:6)
```

To fix it, you need to replace `nextInt()` with something that is tolerant of non-numeric input, possibly [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()). Here is a (very) simple example showing how that could work. Note this is just highlighting the behavior you're asking about, namely: how to address `InputMismatchException`. As with your original program, there is no loop termination – it will run forever (until you quit the program).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("got this: " + s);
}

1 2 3 4 5 6
got this:  2 3 4 5 6
Alice
got this: Alice
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to know is there a way to terminate the loop. I tried using `sc.close()` but it didn't help either. And what's the best way to take these kind of inputs?

Comment: re: _"what's the best way to take these kind of inputs?"_ – Did you read my answer? re: _"I wanted to know is there a way to terminate the loop"_ – Where is that mentioned in your posted question? If your question is "how do I exit the loop", the entire thing should be rewritten to make the question clear, and remove anything about data types, input mismatch, etc

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Kaan Your approach has solved my issue. I just wanted to know further if there was a way to stop the infinite loop? Otherwise my doubt is already solved.

Comment: _"Your approach has solved my issue"_ – Ok great. When someone posts an answer that addresses your question, you should vote up and accept the answer _ this lets everyone know the question has been resolved.

Comment: To exit the loop, you can add code to check for a specific value – maybe the string "exit" – and then break out of the loop (using `break`) if that value is seen.